# Can not draw highchart on modal popup with JsonResult ajax call

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, highcharts

I'm working with Highcharts in MVC 5. I would like to be able to click on a column on a Column chart and have it take the user to a modal popup and show new graph every time and i have also json result data but it can not draw chart as i want. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

So, here is a screen shot of output:
When i pass the json data from controller to highchart the graph shows like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdhpW.png)
and here is highchart javascript:

```js
 plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        colorByPoint: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true
                        },
                        shadow: false,
                        point: {
                            events: {
                                click: function () {

                                    if (this.name === null) {
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                    else {


                                        $('#modalHeaderTitle').text(this.name);

                                        //Get Query string parameter value
                                        var table = getParameterByName('table');
                                        var column = getParameterByName('column');

                                        //Ajax call for get Modal data
                                        $.ajax({
                                            type: "POST",
                                            url: "/NewService/GetModalData",
                                            data: '{tablename: "' + table + '", columname: "' + column +'", name: "' + this.name + '" }',
                                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                            dataType: "json",
                                            success: function (result) {

                                                if (result==='[]') {
                                                    
                                                    bootbox.alert({
                                                        message: "There is no data to show graph?",
                                                        className: 'bb-alternate-modal'
                                                    });

                                                    // Set a timeout to hide the element again
                                                    setTimeout(function () {
                                                        bootbox.hideAll();
                                                    }, 2000);
                                                }
                                                else {

                                                    modaldataSeries = result;
                                                    getModalChart(modaldataSeries);
                                                }
                                            },
                                            error: function (e) {
                                                console.log(e);
                                            }
                                        });

                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

and here is function:

```js
function getModalChart(modaldataSeries) {
    var chart1=$('#container11').highcharts( {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        }
        , title: {
            text: 'Single_Geography_Timeline'
        }
        , xAxis: {
            type: 'category'
        }
        , plotOptions: {
            series: {
                pointPadding: 0, groupPadding: 0.1,
            }
        }
        , series: modaldataSeries, 
         credits: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
    );
    $("#myModal").modal( {
        show: true, backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false
    }
    );
    console.log(modaldataSeries);
    $("#jsonData").text('series :'+modaldataSeries);
}
```

When i tried to set series data manually it show the output properly here is example [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phTgX.png):

i am not able to figure out bug in javascript

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What the result ajax call `/NewService/GetModalData`  return ? You need to check it, add console.log(result). Are you sure that you got the object not the string ?

Comment: the result ajax call /NewService/GetModalData return json data as i posted in image file and also tried in console it print the same json data and yes i am sure about it is object

Comment: Ok. But very suspiciously how this line: $("#jsonData").text('series :'+modaldataSeries); can return the: json string. If the modaldataSeries is the object the output would be: series: [object Object]. The next question if the result is the object why you check it in success callback as the string  (if (result==='[]') {)?

Comment: $("#jsonData").text('series :'+modaldataSeries) this line only print the jsondata as i display in image on top of the graph. Here, i use drilldown highchart. If i don't use (if (result==='[]') {) this then it call modal highchart every time with no data.

Comment: For me very suspiciously  that $("#jsonData").text('series :'+modaldataSeries) is return the string structure of the object.  If modaldataSeries is the object the output would be just: "series :[object Object]" the jquery method $.text cant convert object to string automaticly. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/wh22vqp0/.

Comment: thanks, I clearly understand what you have posted on .  jsfiddle.net/wh22vqp0 . Now, can you told me how to parse json string into json object, I have tried $.parseJSON recently it gives an error like Unexpected token n in JSON for example: this is data [{name:'12',data:[{name:'10188',y:2,drilldown:'10188'}]}]. Is there is way to convert string to json object. Thanks again Alisher

Comment: Your JSON is not a valid JSON - JSON uses double quotes, you can check your json here http://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html

Comment: Your json format is not correct. The correct variant is: [{"name":12,"data":[{"name":10188,"y":2,"drilldown":10188}]}]